# Epson TM-T88IV not printing from Firefox/Chrome in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, printing, epson

I'm using a procedure **successfully** used with Debian 6 and Ubuntu 10.04 - 11.04.

Get drivers from [Epson POS Drivers](https://pos.epson.com/developers/techresdetails.htm?productpk=642)

```
 apt-get install cups libusb-1.0-0 libusb-1.0-0-dev
 unzip TM\ BA\ Series\ Thermal\ Printer\ Driver\ 1100.zip
 cd Epson_TM_Thermal_Printer_Driver_1100/tmt-cups/
 sudo bash install.sh
 sudo chown -R root.root ppd/*.ppd
 sudo cp ppd/*.ppd /usr/share/ppd/openprinting/Epson/ [ or somewhere handy ]
```

Finish installation in CUPS localhost:631

**Problems/Symptoms:**
The Good:

- Prints CUPS test pages successfully
- Prints from xterm: Eg., `lp<<<"My Very Brief TEST PAGE"`
- If web page is printed to PDF *first*, then sent to receipt printer ...it works!

The Bad:

- Does not print from Firefox
- Does not print from Chromium

The Ugly [ Error messages ]:
From CUPS:

> stopped  "/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertotmt failed"

**Other noteworthy facts:**

This printer is a T88IV, Epson does not list drivers for the IV, only the V. So I'm using the drivers for the V --- this works in Windows, by the way, use drivers for V and the IV works just fine.

I've checked permissions for all ppd files and directories and matched them to existing ppd files/directories on the system. Printing to a Xerox works fine.

So, how can I get rid of the `rastertotmt` error above?

Answer (score 1):

I just installed the driver in Lubuntu 13.04 y Ubuntu Gnome 13.04 I downloaded the driver from
http://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=prod&pcat=3&scat=32&pid=30
I installed the driver from
./install.sh and then Use the PPD file for the printer and it worked great T88V

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this! I will be working on this again today and next week and this information couldn't have come at a better time. Good news for me! Thanks again.

Comment: Still can't print from firefox. Different error. Prints from other applications.

Answer (score 0):

in your Download of the printer driver should be a folder called `filter/`.

Copy all the files in it to `/usr/lib/cups/filter`.

Also make sure that all the other files in your Download were copied correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I did this -- I neglected to mention that in my post. Will try with the newest drivers and see how it goes.